# When is the Lagrange interpolation polynomial exact?

Tags: numerical-methods, solution-verification, numerical-linear-algebra, lagrange-interpolation

Find the Lagrange interpolation polynomial for data points $x_k=k$ and $f(k)=k^2$, where $k=0,1,2,3$.
Also, find the Lagrange interpolation polynomial for the same data points but with $g(k)= k^4$.

I would like to say that in both cases the Lagrange polynomial (L.p.) is just the given function, as the number of data points is greater than or equal to the degrees of $f$ and $g$ and the L.p. is unique.

Is this true? More generally when is the Lagrange  interpolation polynomial exact? Many thanks!

Comment: When is the Lagrange polynomial exact? When the function is a polynomial assuming the number of data points is $n+1$, where $n$ is the degree.

Comment: @Chrystomath What if the function has degree less than $n$?  What if the degree matches the number of data points? I assume my answer is incorrect? Thanks!

Comment: The Lagrange polynomial on $n$ data points reproduces a polynomial of degree up to $n-1$. So, on 10 data points, the function $x^n$, $n\le9$ has L.poly $x^n$, but $x^{10}$ has L.poly. equal to some degree 9 poly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the collocation points at $x_k=k$ where $k=0,1,2,3$ with $\mathcal{N}=4$ your Lagrange polynomial $\mathcal{L}(k)$ is of order $\mathcal{P}=3$. This means:

1. For the first function $f_1(k)=k^2$ the Lagrange interpolation polynomial $\mathcal{L_{P=3}}(k)$ is exact.
2. For the second function $f_2(k)=k^4$ the Lagrange interpolation polynomial $\mathcal{L_{P=3}}(k)$ is not exact and only an approximation.

[image]

**You mentioned**:

> "I would like to say that in both cases the Lagrange polynomial (L.p.) is just the given function."

You have to distinguish between the Langrange interpolation problem itself and the representation of the given polynomial.

- In both cases the given functions are not in a **Langrange representation**
  $$\mathcal{L(k)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathcal{P}} a_i \phi_i(k).$$ In the given plots you can see that the i'th basis function $\phi_i$ intersects with $f_1, f_2$ at the i'th collocation point.
- The functions $f_1, f_2$ are in a **Monomial representation**
  $$\mathcal{T(k)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\mathcal{P}} b_i \psi_i(k),$$ where $b_2=1,~\psi_2=k^2$ and $b_4=1,~\psi_4=k^4$

Regards

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!